# How do I split this string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like this:

```
'word','another word','and a sentence','and more','etc etc'
```

I need to split this into two strings, divided by the second comma, which shouldn't show in either of the sentences. What complicates things is that here can also be commas inside the various quotes parts of the string.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: is this complete an array or string ?

Comment: @Phil You will want to double check your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a="'word','another word','and a sentence','and more','etc etc'";

//preg_match('{(.*?,[^,]*),(.*)}', $a, $matches);
preg_match('{(.*?[^\\\\]\',.*?[^\\\\]\'),(.*)}', $a, $matches); //UPDATE 
print_r($matches);
```

DISPLAY:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 'word','another word','and a sentence','and more','etc etc'
    [1] => 'word','another word'
    [2] => 'and a sentence','and more','etc etc'
)
```

Comment: *"What complicates things is that here can also be commas inside the various quotes parts of the string."* - This solution fails if there is a comma in a string.

Comment: yes,if group1 or 2 hv comma ,it fails , i post another solution below use eval("\$arr =  array($a);");

Comment: UPDATE TO preg_match('{(.*?[^\\\\]\',.*?[^\\\\]\'),(.*)}', $a, $matches);  , or \'

Answer (score 1):

This very much looks like CSV syntax, so:

```
$parsed  = str_getcsv($string, ',', "'");
$string1 = join(',', array_slice($parsed, 0, 2));
$string2 = join(',', array_slice($parsed, 2));
```

If your PHP version is below 5.3 and hence you don't have [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv), you can replicate this using a virtual file handle to `php://temp` and `fgetcsv`.

Alternatively, depending on how difficult your syntax is, [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok) can be used for a simple parser. Find the first `'`, then the next `'`, then a `,`, then a `'`, then the next `'` and you have the first part of the string...

Comment: deceze, is there a way for me to keep the quotes around the various parts of the string? str_getcsv strips them all out.

Comment: Then just put them back. `array_map(function ($str) { return "'$str'"; }, $parsed);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that there can be commas in between quotes .. so [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) can help you much better than explode

```
        <?php

                 $string = "'word','another word','and a sentence','and more','etc etc'";
                 $pattern = '%\',\'%';
                 $split = preg_split($pattern,$string);
                 $array1 = array();
                 $array2 = array();
                 foreach($split as $key=>$value)
                 {
                    $value  = trim($value,"'");
                    $value = "'{$value}'";

                    if(($key === 0) || ($key ===1))
                    {
                        $array1[] = $value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $array2[] = $value; 
                    }
                 }

                echo $req_string1 = implode(',',$array1);
                echo "<br>";
                echo $req_string2 = implode(',',$array2);     


             ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

commas in between quotes

```
$a="'word','another word','and a sentence','and more','etc etc'";

eval("\$arr =  array($a);");

$text1='';
$text2='';
foreach($arr AS $k=>$v){
    if($k<2){
        $text1.=$text1?',':'';
        $text1.="'{$v}'";
    }else{
        $text2.=$text2?',':'';
        $text2.="'{$v}'";
    }
}
echo $text1;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $text2;
```

'word','another word'

'and a sentence','and more','etc etc'